# Volley JsonObjectRequest

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

Well I'm just trying to parse json web-service to an array, the problem is only the first item shows on the list-view.what I'm supposed to do to make the full json array appears in the list-view?

```
private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
    showpDialog();
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

            try {
                JSONArray snap = response.getJSONArray("arr_0");
                String[] list = new String[snap.length()];
                 for (int i = 0; i < snap.length(); i++) {
                     list[i] = snap.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
                     list[i] = snap.getJSONObject(i).getString("description");
                     list[i] = snap.getJSONObject(i).getString("url");
                     list[i] = snap.getJSONObject(i).getString("sort");
                     list[i] = snap.getJSONObject(i).getString("attachment_id");
                     list[i] = snap.getJSONObject(i).getString("thumb");
                     list[i] = snap.getJSONObject(i).getString("image");
                     list[i] = snap.getJSONObject(i).getString("height");
                     list[i] = snap.getJSONObject(i).getString("width");
                }
                snapActivity.this.lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(snapActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            hidepDialog();
        }
```

Comment: isn't this showing the `width` of all items in the list ?

Comment: No, it's some data in the json.

Comment: i mean according to your code , list should display width of every entry , if not then post your response json data as well

Comment: I said in the post, it just give the title, i don't know why the rest of the array dont show up

Comment: i guess it must be throwing some exception check or check jsonarray length

Comment: you have to post your `response` as well and yes as @apk mentioned , check if there is any error in log cat , mean `Error` toast is appearing or not

Comment: this is the json response, i just get the first attribute which is title, and if i put anything else at the top of the list i get it instead of title, why i'm just getting the first thing only ?                                                    {"arr_0":[{"title":"M6mp3","description":"#\u0644\u0627\u064a\u0641  \u2705","url":"ViP\ud83c\udf1f","sort":"5","attachment_id":"31006","thumb":"http:\/\/www.world.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/06\/image-150x150.png","image":"http:\/\/www.world.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/06\/image.png","height":"1334","width":"748"}]}

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, you just need to use a custom adapter to populate the data to the listView